# Decoding Hex char string in python

Tags: python, string, hex, byte

I'm trying to interface a software with python via a TCP connection. The software is AGWPE (in fact, it's soundmodem, but they share the same API). 
When I ask the software for "normal" packets, everything fine, but when I ask for "raw" packets, the hex bytes the tcp connection gives me won't decode as nothing at all. Not ASCII, not unicode, not latin-1.

This is the API of AGWPE already to the packet I'm having trouble with:
http://uz7.ho.ua/includes/agwpeapi.htm#_Toc500723814

This is my code:

```
import socket
#import aprslib

raw=1


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 8000
BUFFER_SIZE =  1024
MESSAGE = '000000006D00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
message2 = '000000006B00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
MESSAGE = bytearray.fromhex(MESSAGE)
message2 = bytearray.fromhex(message2)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
if raw:
    s.send(message2)

data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
dataf=data.decode("ascii", 'ignore') #not putting the second argument raises an exception
#aprs=aprslib.parse(dataf)
print(dataf)
s.close()
```

And this is my result: (I would paste it but seems that notepad and the browser don't like some characters)
Raw on:
http://i.gyazo.com/2e6eecf99c6e79c7cdbcf868a734694b.png

I would be expecting something like on the example:

....K...LU7DID..8.LU7DID-4..B...,.E....n......n...i8...[LU7DID@LU7DID-4] B,C,D,E,X,I,M,?,N,P,U,J,R: ..

with the char 0x00 instead of . of course. At least something readable.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Try `data.encode("hex")`. You could also use `repr(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using python 3. Try something like:

```
bytearray.fromhex(data).decode()
```

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.fromhex)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve. Python 3 tells the difference between bytes and str, so it raises an exception:
    dataf=bytearray.fromhex(data).decode()
TypeError: must be str, not bytes